# Errors trying to import FBX

Tags: import, .fbx

I'm trying to import an FBX to blender but I'm getting an error. Any ideas?

[image: Traceback]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to debug the problem from the error text only. What is inside the fbx? Which program did create it? Is it the only fbx you can't import? And so on. Probably this is a bug, so report it at https://developer.blender.org/ but you'll be asked to provide as much information as possible there as well, not only screenshot of the error